# Redirect to login page when not logged in causes state transition error

Tags: authentication, reactjs, react-router, redux, react-router-redux

I am struggling to figure out how to correctly redirect to a login page  when the user is not logged in using React and Redux.

Currently, in the constructor of the component, I check to see if the username is set, and if not, I use the routeActions provided by `redux-simple-router` to redirect to the login page. However, I get this error:

```js
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

I understand that setting the state inside of the render function should be avoided. but I am not sure where I should detect and redirect. I have also tried checking the auth state in the `componentWillReceiveProps` and `ComponentWillMount`, but no luck.

```js
// WordListContainer.js
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {routeActions} from 'redux-simple-router';

import WordList from '../components/Words/WordList';
import {addWord, editWord, deleteWord, fetchWords} from '../actions/words';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth,
    words: state.words
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    router: bindActionCreators(routeActions, dispatch),
    actions: bindActionCreators({
      addWord, editWord, deleteWord, fetchWords
    }, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(WordList);
```

and

```js
// WordList.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import WordListItem from './WordListItem';

export default class WordList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    if(!this.props.auth.username) {
      // This redirection causes the error
      this.props.router.push('/login');
    }
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a good place where I can check the state and redirect before even trying to render the component? Perhaps somehow using the Container Object, though I am not quite sure how to do it where I have access to both state and dispatch.

Comment: My initial thought is to encapsulate the transition in a thunk using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Answer (score 1):

try componentDidUpdate() as this lifecycle method will always be called whenever the state changes.